# How to plot two values as a histogram using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have to plot two values as a histogram using python.

```
 File=[1,2,3] 
 File1=[3,4,5,6] 
 files=len(File) 
 files1=len(File1)
```

I want to plot the length of the files. `files` and `files1` should be on the x-axis and the y-axis needs to have the count like 0, 10, 20 ....

Below is an example diagram.
[image: Example bar plot]

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the result you want a little more fully?

Comment: I do not understand the question, please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a [bar plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar([0, 1], [files, files1])
plt.show()
```

Check out the [matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/gallery.html) if you want to find out how to format and change labels, axis limits, etc.

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks @kazemakase. But i need a bar like what i have mentioned in sample picture. Could you please give me an idea how to get that?

Comment: @sara what exactly do you mean? There are two bars, one is 3 units high, the other 4 - just like in your example. Everything else is just a matter of formatting the axis range and the tick labels.